# SQL CLR Data Base Project / Assembly on VS2017

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to create my first CLR procedure for training purposes and looks like step #1 is to create DataBase project under , but I can't see it under mine setup, even I did install all I could with DataTools 2017.
I have SQL Server under VB only but I think it's not right one for CLR.

Do I need to install something extra ?
[image]

Comment: I bet that database project is in the guide to ease deployment of database articles, however, I doubt it is required. I have deployed assemblies to sql using simple scripts. To answer your question, it sounds like you did not do a complete install of VS. Perhaps you can add/remove programs and see if the database tools is an option.

Comment: Thanks Ross, I'm checking, also found this link with good info  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272683(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Just reinstall most recent datatools (as of Dec 20, 2018). Same result, anybody see SQL Project in VS 2017 under C#???

Comment: Found that it's a problem reported before:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/166536/ssdt-not-present-in-visual-studio-build-tools-2017.html

Comment: Thanks all, I need do more homework, existing SQL Server project I htink will work OK.